# How to save row values from one field in subform to main form record? - Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016, subform

I have a parent form (frmGroupSession) that has a subform (SubFormParticipants) in datasheet view.  The subform is based off a query that selects all participants ([CLIENT ID], [NAME], [ATTENDED]) that had attended a specific group [GroupID] on a specific date [GroupSessionDate]. The parent form saves to a table that logs group sessions (tblGroupSessionLog).  I need to save the group's participants [CLIENT ID] to the record within tblGroupSessionLog

Basically, I need to pass data from the subform to the record within tblGroupSessionLog. I'm not sure what the most effective way to do this, if it's possible at all.  Ideally, I would like to have each unique participant [CLIENT ID] stored in its own field within tblGroupSessionLog.  If there were 20 participants in the subform then each row value from the first column/field [CLIENT ID] would be passed to the corresponding field within tblGroupSessionLog ([ClientID1] thru [ClientID20])

I am relatively new at this.  Even asking the question was difficult.

I am not sure what else I can provide to help you wizards with the solve, but let me know and I will.

Thoughts?  Ideas?

Comment: My first impression is that a table with a field for each participant makes little sense. Instead of saving to a table, maybe you need a CROSSTAB query. Question is too broad and lacks any attempt to solve issue (which will require VBA code), therefore is not really appropriate for SO and will likely be closed.

Comment: Having said that, I do confess to using 'temp' tables to temporarily hold data in non-normalized structure for report output. Is this the basis of your requirement? Review https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=21972

Answer (score 0):

Access 101 :  You have a many to many relationship You should look that term up but in short it means clients can belong to many groups and each group can have many clients.  (so bang your data into a normalized structure similar to the following:
[image]

First tip make sure to add the relationships under database tools (you should look that up).  Access needs to know how the tables are related to manage the keys behind the scenes and sometimes access makes better decisions about automatic form creating when it already knows the relationship structure.  Once your data is properly structured access makes it easy to produce functional if much less than styling data entry forms which can also be used as even worse search forms.  For instance Click on any table and hit create form on the ribbon and access will create the data entry form form you.
[image]

Basic Style tip 1:  Always delete primary key fields like ClientID from the form.  The field is still there in the form's record source being managed by access.  Users almost never need to see any table keys.  This gives you a basic data entry form which you can also use to scroll through any clients you have entered using the record selector circled at the bottom of the frmClients.
[image]

Play around with the record selector to see how it works.  In particular go past the last record and you will find you can enter new clients and access will automatically give them a ClientID.  You can also cycle through your Clients and update them using this form it just isn't stylish.  In the same way we can make a form for the groups table.
You make a form for the frmGroupSessions table in the same manner as the others but add a step.  Replace the text boxes holding ClientID and GroupID with human readable comboboxes.  Here is a link to help with that: https://www.google.com/search?q=access+change+text+box+to+combo+box&oq=access+change+text+&aqs=chrome.0.0i457j0l2j69i57j0j0i22i30l2.7503j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_r0sFYJ7vBcfY5gLz2aTgBw15

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

At this point play around to learn.  Use the Record Selector at the bottom of frmGroupSessions to add and modify data.  Play with the Tables and see what happens.  Start messing with the form properties in particular the default view.  Soon you will have ideas about how the form could be better and you can start figuring out how to style them.