# Access insert into with criteria from form

Tags: forms, ms-access, sql-insert

I'm using MS Access and there is something I can't do.

I have a form named "AddNewComp". I have a text field named "CompName" and a button in the form which execute an insert query.

To pass values, in the query, I add the following text in the criteria section : `[Forms]![AddNewComp]![CompName]`

Now, when I click the button, I have a prompt "Enter value for [Forms]![AddNewComp]![CompName]". But the value should be the text I wrote in the field. I've already tried with `[Forms]![AddNewComp]![CompName].[Text]`.

What's wrong with what am I doing ?

Comment: This is a classic. The query, when executed from code, have no idea of what your form is. You have to pass the value for the parameter in the code as well. Bing/google for a ton of examples how to achieve this.

Comment: I understand. I already searched it, and the ton of examples are about passing the value with VBA. Is it possible to not achieve this with VBA ?

Comment: It is indeed. However, SO is not a code writing but a code helper forum. If you are in the wild, turn to fora like UtterAccess, Bytes.com, and Experts-Exchange where also files can be attached and downloaded.

Comment: Thanks ! No problem with VBA, I just wanted to avoid using multiple sources for 1 action :).

Comment: If you have a dynamic parameterized query with the parameter as a reference to control on form, it should work. For some reason Access is not finding the control. I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. Why are you using INSERT to create record anyway and not a bound form?

Comment: Access provides the means to rapidly create forms for search and data-entry which are bound to your data.  You should have tried that approach before going the button vba route.  That is what June7 means by using a bound form.  Here is a link to an example of creating a bound form for a many to many relationship I produced while answering a stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765483/how-to-save-row-values-from-one-field-in-subform-to-main-form-record-access/65771786#65771786  .

Comment: Anyway for the official question as June7 has commented Access is telling you it can't find the control.  Check for a mis-spelling or a closed form.  After that it is probably easier to just pass the parameters from your loading form to the report rather than provide all the details we will need to find the error.  Here is another link for passing parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398804/pass-a-parameter-into-an-access-report-programmatically

Comment: I didn't use bound form because I was thinking about something else with the button. Anyway, I'm gonna use it now :). Thank you @mazoula for the links !